# What is the name and how would you implement Instagram or Spotify scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uiscrollview

When scrolling through Instagram, the username bar locks or freezes at the top of each user until the next username bar replaces it at the top.

When scrolling through Artist pages the artist name and "Shuffle Play" button scrolls up until it reaches the top and is then locked/frozen at the top.

What's the name of this scrolling so I can find more information on it? And how would I implement it in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are tableView's sections like the letters in the contacts apps (A, B, C, D).